# Windows Server 2008 automatic shutdown before reaching login screen

Tags: windows-server-2008, login

I have a Windows Server 2008 machine on a domain that will not stay powered on. During startup I see:

"Applying Computer Settings"
then "Applying Registry Policy"
then "Applying Group Policy Registry Policy"
then quickly flashes "Please wait for the Local Session Manager..."
then quickly flashes "Shutting down Group Policy Client service..."
then "Stopping services..." 
then "Shutting down"

It never reaches the <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>dlt</kbd> screen.

I can get into safe mode with networking and when I try to force a group policy update it says that the user policy update failed. The event viewer shows quite a few group policy failures.

Help!

Comment: Since you can get into safe mode... take a gander at the event logs. On a server that can't even boot, they're bound to say *something* of interest.

Answer (score 0):

Boot into safe mode and run `sfc /scannow` and see if it makes any repairs.

If not, recover from Last Known Good Configuration, or a system state backup.